# Import conversions to ExactTarget

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am trying to import conversions into Exact Target so that I can take advantage of its reporting abilities.

Assuming I have the subscriberID, jobID, and conversionAmount (dollar amounts) being collected on a server, how do I get this into ExactTarget.

I've created the necessary Data Extension and the respective Import Activity. How do I now enter these numbers into the necessary table to be able to view conversions in the Tracking sub-module?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm 99% sure you cannot directly do what you are asking.  SubscriberID and JobID are not (with only 1 exception I can think of) externally writable fields. You may be able to do what you're looking to do with a custom extract engagement with the ET services team.

Comment: as a clarification, subscriberid and jobid would serve as foreign keys. the conversion data would be the new data.

Answer (score 0):

Absent the ability to change the code on the checkout portion of the site (in this case, an external site), the solution that I have found is to simply write a script that requests the tracking pixels once a day using the data provided by my shopping cart vendor.

The instructions for setting the pixels' parameter are here:

http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/conversion_tracking/

I'm still testing this and have not yet successfully tracked conversions in the Tracking sub-module.